# Unable To Import Variable from __init__.py

Tags: python

I have some like this:

```
/package
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
```

and inside `__init__.py` I define `some_variable=True`

When I try to import `some_variable` inside my files

```
from . import some_variable
```

I get `ImportError: cannot import name some_variable`.

I get the same error if I do

```
from folder.package import some_variable
```

Why am I not able to import this variable?

The really confusing/frustrating part is that PyCharm's autocomplete recognises that the variable exists.

Comment: `from package import some_variable` gives `ImportError: No module named package`.

Comment: have you tried `from folder.package import *` or `from . import *`

Comment: `from . import *` works. Which is still confusing to me.

Comment: does `__init__.py` have `__all__` global declared?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your error. Could you create a minimal working example please -- fully specifying the contents of `__init__` and `file1`, and where how you're running the program. Do you at any point in `__init__` import a sub module?